# how to print out data and organize with selected option in python

Tags: python, tkinter

guys I am currently studying python. I faced issues which is how to print out this tkinter in a frame
So, now with my code. it is just print out like;
A
13:00pm
17:00pm
B
C
High

but I want organize this date look like;
ex)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejLt9.png)

Also how to make calculate function and print out like this photo?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR6y3.png)

I need you guys favor, please help and teach me from this issues.

Thank you.

this is my code

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter.ttk import*
from tabulate import tabulate

win = Tk()
win.geometry("500x500")
win.title("Schedule")

#textbox
Label(win, text="Date").pack()
ent1 = Entry(win)
ent1.pack()

def ent_p():
    a = ent1.get()
    print(a)


#Combobox_starttime
Label(win, text="Start time").pack()
cb_list1 = ["8:00am","9:00am","10:00am","11:00am","12:00pm","13:00pm","14:00pm","15:00pm","16:00pm","17:00pm"]
cb1 = Combobox(win)
cb1.config(values = cb_list1)
cb1.pack()

#Combobox_endtime
Label(win, text="End time").pack()
cb_list2 = ["9:00am","10:00am","11:00am","12:00pm","13:00pm","14:00pm","15:00pm","16:00pm","17:00pm","18:00pm"]
cb2 = Combobox(win)
cb2.config(values = cb_list2)
cb2.pack()
       
    
    
Label(win, text="Subject").pack()
ent2 = Entry(win, width = 25)
ent2.pack()

def ent_p():
    b = ent2.get()
    print(b)

Label(win, text="Venue").pack()
ent3 = Entry(win, width = 25)
ent3.pack()

def ent_p():
    c = ent3.get()
    print(c)

    
#Radio button
priority = [("High", "High"),("Medium", "Medium"),("Low", "Low"),]

Label(win, text="Priority").pack()
rv = StringVar()
for text, mode in priority:
    rb1 = Radiobutton(win, text = text, value = mode, variable = rv)
    rb1.pack()



#Button
btn = Button(win)
btn.config(text = "Appointment")

def click():
    lab_text1 = ent1.get()
    lab1.config(text = lab_text1)

        
    lab_text2 = cb1.get()
    lab2.config(text = lab_text2)
    
    
    lab_text3 = cb2.get()
    lab3.config(text = lab_text3)
    
    
    lab_text4 = ent2.get()
    lab4.config(text = lab_text4)
    
    
    lab_text5 = ent3.get()
    lab5.config(text = lab_text5)
    
    
    lab_text6 = rv.get()
    lab6.config(text = lab_text6)
    
    #print function, Need to code for isValidDate(),isValidTime() data.
    
    d = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]]
    print(tabulate(d, headers=["Date", "Start", "End", "Subject", "Venue", "Priority"]))

    
    
    
btn.config(command = click)

btn.pack()





#Label
lab1 = Label(win)
lab1.pack()
lab2 = Label(win)
lab2.pack()
lab3 = Label(win)
lab3.pack()
lab4 = Label(win)
lab4.pack()
lab5 = Label(win)
lab5.pack()
lab6 = Label(win)
lab6.pack()



win.mainloop()


# In[19]:


pip install tabulate 


# In[ ]:
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] and your attempts to solve the issue

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).